# How to align div vertically in the center?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to align a div vertically in the center of my browser only with CSS usage?

Comment: This, my friend, is an age old problem which is best solved with JavaScript/jQuery rather then purely CSS, there is not bulletproof, 100% clean CSS solution that also works in every browser. JavaScript however makes this easy. You should consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            html {
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%
            }
            body {
                display: table-row;
                margin: 0;
                height: 100%
            }
            #foo {
                display: table-cell;
                height: 100%;
                vertical-align: middle
            }
            #test {
                margin: auto;
                background-color: #ccc
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foo">
            <div id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dislike the fact that you need more elements.

Comment: That was the best solution ! :)

Thanks a lot Shadow2531 !!